# React js - Block scrolling in the upwards direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my application, I have a `List` component where as a user scrolls up, more data is loaded. When the user has reached the end of the list and there is no more data, I set the `scrollBlocked` state variable to true meaning a user shouldn't be able to scroll up further.

I have an `onScroll` event on my `List`, which calls the function `disable` everytime a user scrolls.

`List` Component:

```
<List onScroll={(e) => disable(e)} />
```

`Disable` function:

```
  function disable(e) {
    const newScrollPosition = e.target.scrollTop;
    if (!scrollBlocked) {
      setScrollPosition(newScrollPosition);
    }

    // Code to completely stop a user scrolling in any direction. 
    //Here is where I want to implement logic to allow scrolling downwards, however disable scrolling upwards
    if (scrollBlocked) {
      e.target.scrollTo({
        top: scrollPosition,
        left: 0
      });
    }
}
```

This code blocks the user scrolling in any direction if `scrollBlocked` has been set to `true`. However, I would still like a user to be able to scroll down if `scrollBlocked` is `true`, so they can see the previous data. How could I accomplish only disabling scrolling upwards, and allowing a user to still scroll downwards if `scrollBlocked` has been set to true? Thanks.

Comment: What is the reason you want to block scrolling though? That would be very bad User Experience.

Comment: @ElvisAdomnica So that users cannot load anymore data by scrolling up, as I am using an Infinite Loader List. The solution I am implementing is the most effective at the time being.

Comment: then why not use the flag variable to block (aka prevent) new data fetch instead? why would you mess with the scroll?

Comment: For instance, if I am at the top of the page on Chrome on mobile and I want to refresh the page, I can use scroll up as a gesture to trigger the refresh. Your code would mess that experience and would frustrate your users.

Comment: maybe we are using scroll-up and down terms in reverse though :D